# Dotnetnuke 7 .less integration

Tags: responsive-design, less, dotnetnuke

We are looking to create responsive skin for a Dotnetnuke 7 installation

We have done this before by just writing the code and using winless to compile it and uploading the css.

This worked ok but having recently made an umbraco site with support for .less files (using uless) the process was a lot smoother

I have tried to research the subject but can't dig up anything more recent that this

http://www.xram.net/blog/2010/6/9/integrating-dotless-dynamic-css-with-dotnetnuke/

Which is from 2010, so several versions of dnn ago

Has anyone got something like this working in a recent version?

If so does it break after upgrades

I would even consider using a 3rd party module if there is one available but i couldn't find one

Answer (score 0):

We use less with our DNN implementation. We use the dotless.compiler.exe and a simple batch file to compile the less and copy it to the desired location. So our modules/portals deal with the compiled css but our skins folder contains the less. Batch file looks something like this:

```
@set svnRootDir=C:\Projects\MyMantra
@set deployDir=D:\Web\Public\BrandSites\Website\Portals\_default\Skins

%svnRootDir%\Scripts\Packaging\dotless.compiler.exe %svnRootDir%\MG\Skins\Skins\Breakfree\css\*.less
robocopy %svnRootDir%\MG\Skins\Skins\Breakfree\ %deployDir%\Breakfree\ /s /XF *.less *.htm *.html
```

NOTE: robocopy /s - Copy Subdirectories, but not empty ones and /XF - eXclude Files matching given names/paths/wildcards.

I prefer this over what is mentioned in that blog post since it doesn't mean a core change and you keep the DNN core vanilla so upgrades don't cause any problems.